# Display only if data item exists 3 or more times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large excel file with phone numbers listed in one of the columns.  In that column, I would like to filter the results for the phone numbers that show up 3 or more times.  I don't want any of the other data in the excel file to disappear either.

So far, I have tried Conditional Formatting.  However, I didn't get very far because the only formula that I could think to use would be "countif" and that's based on pre-defined criteria, whereas I have 30,000 different phone numbers listed here and I need to only highlight the items that show up 3 or more times.

Please help me?

Comment: Have you tried the `COUNTIF()` function in a column next to the phone numbers and filtering on only rows that show >= 3?

Comment: No.  I haven't.  I'm really trying to get results solely based on those phone numbers.  In case it's not clear, I have columns A through N filled.  The only column that's of interest here is the one with the phone numbers in it.  However, those results need to have the supporting data to go along with them.

Comment: Use conditional formatting with `=countif(A:A, A1)<3` and a custom cell number format of `;;;`.

Comment: @Jeeped, I'm unsure what the ;;; would do???

Comment: It doesn't show anything in the cell. But of course, you would know that if you had tried it.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that I don't understand your response.. what would i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column 'Count' and use the `COUNTIF()` function like this (see below)... Then filter.

[image: Phone Number List Count using COUNTIF Function]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you!  i appreciate it!   i understand this much better

Comment: It worked!  I'm sending the results now!  Thank you!